# print the cost of maximum and minimum path in an undirected weigted connected graph

Tags: c++, graph, path, depth-first-search

we are given the starting node , we have to return the cost of minimum and maximum path, in which all the nodes get visited.
For ex: In the given figure: Starting Node=1 
        minimum path: 1->2->3
        minimum cost: 7
        maximum path: 1->3->2
        maximum cost: 10[image]

I am trying to solve this problem but not able to find a solution to this. Can you help me with the logic

Comment: sounds like a fun exercise. Do you have any question?

Comment: we're waiting for a question not a programming puzzle

Comment: have a look at the Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: how you represent your graph?